# How to pass a variable inside a function inside a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

So I'm working with a google map api.
I have to insert the values lat and lon inside of the object, but I can't do something like:

```
$.get(url).done(buscaGPS(data, i));

function buscaGPS(data, i) {

}
```

CODE

```
objecto = [{
    "address_1": "Avenida da Republica, 15A",
    "city": "Lisbon",
    "country": "pt",
    "id": 1534282,
    "name": "Pastelaria Versailles"
}, {
    "address_1": "Avenida da Republica, 15A",
    "city": "Lisbon",
    "country": "pt",
    "id": 1534282,
    "name": "Pastelaria Versailles"
}];


for (var i = 0; i < objecto.length; i++) {
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + objecto[i].address_1 + "+" + objecto[i].city + "+" + objecto[i].country + "&sensor=false";
    $.get(url).done(buscaGPS);
};



function buscaGPS(data) {

    objecto[i].lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    objecto[i].lon = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have problem with? There seem to be 2 functions with the same name in your code - not sure if it is intentional or just copy paste error.

Comment: You have buscaGPS function declared twice. I would try removing the first declaration and running the code again to see if they are conflicting.

Comment: ah i get it. You need to match the index to the response so you can put the response data in the right place?

Comment: No, that twice should be the parte where I had the doubt. I have to edit to separate from the code. Yes Shanimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you mean you want to do something like...

```
// create a closure to capture the index
function callback(index){
    return function(data) {
        objecto[index].lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        objecto[index].lon = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < objecto.length; i++) {
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + objecto[i].address_1 + "+" + objecto[i].city + "+" + objecto[i].country + "&sensor=false";
    $.get(url).done(callback(i));
}
```

Comment: `$.get(url).done(buscaGPS);

$.get(url).done(function(results){
    buscaGPS(results,i);
});

function buscaGPS(data,z){
  console.log(z);
  objecto[z].lat=data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
}

Console:
success
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of undefined
0`

Made a mistake and I saw it when I was editing this.

Comment: data.results[0].geometry.location is undefined... what does your result set look like? can you pastebin "data"?

Comment: I made a mistake here $.get(url).done(buscaGPS); I forget to delete it. Thanks for your help. it is working now. It is shamefully simple :).

The response was has you originally you write it.

`$.get(url).done(function(results){
        buscaGPS(results,i);
    });`

Comment: i'd be careful with your response. in your function the variable i is the last index of the iterator, not the index of the iterator when the function was called. creating a closure will store the value

Comment: Yes. I never thought that I could get an answer so fast. I was in loop in this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While Shanimal's solution is perfectly reasonable, it adds a bit of complexity to the code with the function-returning-a-function. You don't actually need that to get a closure; a simple function call will do the trick.

Consider this alternative:

```
for( var i = 0;  i < objecto.length;  i++ ) {
    geocode( objecto[i] );
}

function geocode( place ) {
    var url =
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
        place.address_1 + "+" + place.city + "+" + place.country +
        "&sensor=false";
    $.get(url).done( function( data ) {
        var location = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        place.lat = location.lat;
        place.lon = location.lng;
    });
}
```

Note that this also gets rid of all the `objecto[i]` and `objecto[index]` references, using a simple `place` variable to replace them.

I find this approach to be much easier to understand than a function that returns a function.

Other comments related to geocoding: Will you have a larger number of locations in your `objecto` array? If it's more than a few, you will need to slow down the geocoding requests instead of firing them all in a row.

Also, if these are fixed locations, you ought to geocode them once and store the lat/long in your array, so you won't have to geocode them at all in the browser. This will make your map load faster and avoid problems with geocoding multiple addresses.

Comment: Humm I never thought this way. Sometimes I have some difficulty understanding javascript objects. Yes when I try to understand what is happening I can't get why Shanimal can access to data using a return ( `return function(data)`). I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Yes, I already saw the botleneck from google api.

"you won't have to geocode them at all in the browser."
I dind't get very well what you were saying. Are you saying that I should geocode in the server?

Comment: Yes, if you are dealing with a fixed set of locations, it's much better to geocode them once and be done with it. If the locations are in a database, you can add a column (or two columns) for the lat/lng and run a geocoding process on your server to populate those columns. Once that's done, you'll never have to geocode them again. If you don't know the locations ahead of time, then of course you can geocode them in the browser, but it takes longer that way.

Comment: Yes, they are fixed. I have to do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: michael, its a matter of scope i suppose. Your closure is inside your get, mine is inside callback. I think yours is somewhat cleaner approach, but only because it make use of converting the complex object into a variable "place" that makes it easier to read. At the end of the day, its the same answer. quit poaching. :) lol

Comment: @Shanimal - No one is poaching; I'm not sure what that would even mean in this context. We're all here to help each other out. As I mentioned, there was nothing wrong with the code you posted - it will certainly do the job. At the same time, I think it's valuable to look for ways to simplify code while fixing bugs or making other changes. In particular, a function returning a function can be a hard concept to follow, so when there is a way to do the same thing with a simple function call, that's worth exploring.

Comment: @Michael Geary - Your answer helped me. We could suggest a plethora of improvements (renaming `objecto` to `places`) or CodeGolf with Array.forEach) I was chiding about poaching because the spirit of the answer is the very same, which is more about creating scope to preserve index and less about making it smaller or legible. I'm truly not upset. I in fact like the large function that encapsulates the geocoding of "place". You might even consider wrapping the `for` loop in a function... `geoCodeAllPlaces(places)`. No ill memories my friend, this is a learning experience for everyone...